# Cython - properly declaring C funs

Tags: c, cython

I'm having trouble with running a bare example.

I'm using this to declare a function in Cython coming from `cinterf.h` header:

```
cdef extern from 'cinterf.h':  
int xsb_init_string(char* p_xsb_path)
```

The declaration in the C header file is:

```
DllExport extern int call_conv xsb_init_string(char *);
```

both DllExport and call_conv are macros defined elsewhere, and resolve to GCC compiler directives.
do I have to use those as well inside cdef to fully match the declaration?

When I call `xsb_init_string()` as:

```
xsb_init_string('some string')
```

The python interpreter gives me:

```
'ImportError: ./py_ext.so: undefined symbol: xsb_init_string'
```

Am I declaring the `xsb_init_string()` signature properly, inside cdef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link to the DLL the library that contains the implementation of `xsb_init_string`.

If you are using `distutils` to compile the Cython module, you can pass options to the linker to include libraries.

Comment: I had a feeling it might be that. I'll give it a shot.   thank you